# How to step out after each warning message?

Tags: excel, vba

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Cells.CheckSpelling SpellLang:=2057
If Range("F4").Value = 1 Then                                                  
    MsgBox "MARKED UP BUDGET does not equal TOTAL! Please amend as required"
    Application.Run "LATESTMEDIAPLANVERSION.xlsm!final"
```

I currently have two pieces of code that yield warning boxes. However at the moment these pop up but don't eject you from the macro.. I.E I just want to ensure that the line:

```
Application.Run......
```

is only reached if you don't prompt the warning box.  What is the the right code for this?.

Comment: add and `else` ... `end if` around the `Application.Run` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Cells.CheckSpelling SpellLang:=2057


If Range("F4").Value = 1 Then                                                  

     MsgBox "MARKED UP BUDGET does not equal TOTAL! Please amend as required"
     Exit Sub

else

    Application.Run "LATESTMEDIAPLANVERSION.xlsm!final"

end if
```

Comment: this is giving me the message but not ejecting me from the macro.. I need something that says: MsgBox "MARKED UP BUDGET does not equal TOTAL! Please amend as required"   "exit macro". else application.run...

Comment: Misunderstood your question - I thought you just didn't want the "Application.Run" line... I have added `Exit Sub`. Consider editing your question for clarity?